# How to get last item from getItems ? using javascript map

Tags: javascript

I need to get last values from items

What i try :

```
val.links.map((link: any) => console.log('link' , link.href))
```

i got results:

```
   link https://api/v1/3
   link https://api/v1/3/user
   link https://api/v1/3/customer
   link https://api/v1/3/suppliers
```

WHat i need
I need to get last item from link

example to get:
*3, user, customer, suppliers*

If you want to see all my api data is:

```
   {
    id: 1,
    links: [
    0: {href: "https://api/3" }
    1: {href: "https://api/user" }
    2: {href: "https://api/customer" }
    3: {href: "https://api/suppliers" }
  ]}
```

Comment: does `links[links.length - 1]` work?

Comment: try `val.links[links.length - 1]`

Comment: There are many things a vast number of people do wrong, like mix up "then" and "than", think "french" fries are "French", or use `map` instead of `forEach`, and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here

> Thanks georg for this suggestion
>
> ```
> const result = obj.links.map((o) => o.href.split("/").pop());
> ```

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  links: [
    { href: "https://api/3" },
    { href: "https://api/user" },
    { href: "https://api/customer" },
    { href: "https://api/suppliers" },
  ],
};

const result = obj.links.map((o) => {
  const matches = o.href.split("/");
  return matches[matches.length - 1];
});

console.log(result);
```

**2)** Using regex `/.*(?=\/)/`

[image]

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  links: [
    { href: "https://api/3" },
    { href: "https://api/user" },
    { href: "https://api/customer" },
    { href: "https://api/suppliers" },
  ],
};

const result = obj.links.map((o) => o.href.replace(/.*(?=\/)/, "").slice(1));

console.log(result);
```

**3)** Using regex `/.*(?=\/)/`

```js
const obj = {
  id: 1,
  links: [
    { href: "https://api/3" },
    { href: "https://api/user" },
    { href: "https://api/customer" },
    { href: "https://api/suppliers" },
  ],
};

const result = obj.links.map((o) => o.href.match(/.*\/(.*)/)[1]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: or simply `.split('/').pop()`

Comment: @yajoj98337 _"example to get: ['3', 'user', 'customer', 'suppliers']"_ - Your question tells another story. But even then you should be able to make that tiny adjustment on your own...